# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object python function

Tags: python, functional-programming, nested

I am coding an ultimate tictactoe game alongside an AI to play against a user. In order to determine where the AI will place their O, I have coded the following:

```
def AIsemidecentboy(allowed, grid):
print("hi")
x = allowed[0] # x = the location from where man is allowed to be
y = allowed[1] #variable y =the location from where man is allowed to be on the y plane
if allowed[0] == -1 and allowed[1] == -1:
    for x in range(allowed[0]+1, (allowed[0] + 10)): # when x is in the range of the x plane allowed positions
        for y in range(allowed[1]+1, (allowed[1] + 10)): # when y is in the range of the y plane allowed positions
            if grid[x][y] == 0: # if the position in the grid is not filled
                print(x,y)
                return(x, y) #return the first possible filling positions
else: # if the location where man is allowed to be isnt simply the whole thing and therefore is one of the minicubes
    for x in range(allowed[0], (allowed[0] + 3)): #when x is in the range of the 3 different x positions it can be in
        for y in range(allowed[1], (allowed[1] + 3)):# when y is in the range of the 3 different y positions it can be in
            if grid[x][y] == 0:
                print("MANLIKE")
                print(x,y)# if the position on the grid is available
                if grid[x][y+1] == 1:
                    print("hellman")
                    print(x,y)
                    return(x, y)
                elif grid[x][y-1] == 1:  
                    print(x,y)
                    print("hellman")                       # For all of these simply observe the notebook
                    return(x, y)
                elif grid[x+1][y] == 1:
                    print(x,y)
                    print("hellman")
                    return(x,y)
                elif grid[x+1][y+1] == 1:
                    print(x,y)
                    print("hellman")
                    return(x,y)
                elif grid[x-1][y+1] == 1:
                    print(x,y)
                    print("hellman")
                    return(x,y)
                elif grid[x+1][y-1] == 1:
                    print(x,y)
                    print("hellman")
                    return(x,y)
                elif grid[x-1][y-1] == 1:
                    print(x,y)
                    print("hellman")
                    return(x,y) 
            else: 
                print("filip")
                for x in range(allowed[0], (allowed[0] + 3)): #when x is in the range of the 3 different x positions it can be in
                    for y in range(allowed[1], (allowed[1] + 3)):# when y is in the range of the 3 different y positions it can be in
                        if grid[x][y] == 0:
                            print(x,y)
                            return(x,y)
```

this function is meant to return a value for both x and y that can then be inputted as the decision made by the algorithm. The ranges exist because one can either place their x/o on the 9 by 9 field or in specific 3 by 3 boxes depending on a randomization function performed by the game.

The function works the first time it is invoked and goes to the final else where "filip" is printed, however after this, the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/skanderlejmi/Desktop/ask.py", line 398, in <module>
xcord, ycord = AIsemidecentboy([allowedx, allowedy], grid)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I presume that for some reason the code that initiated the function is pulling the x and y values before they have been determined or that the function is returning nullified x and y values. Either way, I am particularly confused as to why on one occasion, the function goes through to the else at the end but on another, it does not.

I would really appreciate anyones help on this matter as I am still a beginner with this.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana I have done so

Comment: you never hit a case that returns, so your function returns `None`. also, this is not functional programming, but it is very nested.

Comment: Dear future programmers, when you find this question please note how the puzzle was unlocked by the OP when the full error traceback was added which allowed acushner to be able to provide a diagnosis.